# PingFedrate SSO with WCF REST API

Tags: wcf, rest, pingfederate

I am creating a WCF REST API to be consumed by a ASP.NET web application and mobile applications and an outlook add-in. The current infrastructure is hosted on premise but we plan to take it to the cloud soon.

The API needs to authenticate AD users via PingFedrate SSO. The current classic ASP application integrates PingFedrate and throws a challenge window to the user for authentication. I need to get the same via the API but stuck as to how to begin and where shall it lead.

Any pointers of suggestion from you experts?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you could use PingFederate's OAuth support for.

We (Ping Identity - my employer) have more information on how to authenticate using PingFederate SSO to get OAuth API Access Tokens (to secure your API and tie identity to it) on our Developer Portal.

Please see the follow links/articles:

- https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/learn.html
- https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/oauth-2-0-developers-guide.html
- https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/openid-connect-developers-guide.html